# How to read and increment the application version from/to gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile where I read the current version of the application from gradle version attribute. Based on this version, a docker image is built and pushed to a remote repository.

However, I don't know how to 1. Increment the application version and 2. Push that change to the repository. This is my current Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("build") {
            steps {
               sh './gradlew -q properties > gprops'
               script {
                 buildVersion = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'cat gprops |grep version:|awk \'{print $2}\'').trim()
                 buildName = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'cat gprops |grep name:|awk \'{print $2}\'').trim()
               }
               sh './gradlew clean build -x test'
            }
        }

        stage("build image") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'building the docker image'
                    withCredentials([
                        usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'docker-hub-repo', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')
                    ]) {
                        sh "docker build -t somename/${buildName}:${buildVersion} ."
                        sh "echo $PASSWORD | docker login -u $USER --password-stdin"
                        sh "docker push somename/${buildName}:${buildVersion}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

aa

Comment: Is the version stored in `gradle.properties` in the project itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add gradle task to do so for example

```
version='1.0.0'  //version we need to change

task increment<<{
    def v=buildFile.getText().find(version) //get this build file's text and extract the version value
    String minor=v.substring(v.lastIndexOf('.')+1) //get last digit
    int m=minor.toInteger()+1                      //increment
    String major=v.substring(0,v.length()-1)       //get the beginning
    //println m
    String s=buildFile.getText().replaceFirst("version='$version'","version='"+major+m+"'")
    //println s
    buildFile.setText(s) //replace the build file's text
}
```

Then you can call it with
 `sh './gradlew  increment'` in your pipe , this should increase the version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 .